# mysql is not inserting array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, insert

I dont know why is not inserting the values of the array in the db, I parse the array, but the values in the db are not changing, I manually add some data to the db table  :

```
public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        global $wpdb;
        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "cbrrate";
        $limit=12;
        $i=$x=0;
        $currency = array();

        $codes = array('USD','EUR');
        //creando la tabla 
        if( $wpdb->get_var("SHOW TABLES LIKE '$table_name'") != $table_name)
        {
                $sql = 'CREATE TABLE ' .$table_name . '(
                hit_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
                code CHAR(3),
                rate FLOAT UNSIGNED,
                PRIMARY KEY  (code) )';

        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
        dbDelta($sql);

        }

            //initialise an array to hold the values to be inserted
            $sqlParts1=array();
        //loop through the code to create an array with keys as value
            foreach($codes as $code){




                    //add the rate to the sql query
                    $sqlParts1[] = "('$code', ".((float)$currency[0][$code]).") ";

            }


        $sql = "INSERT INTO $table_name (code, rate) VALUES ".implode(', ', $sqlParts1).' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE rate = VALUES(rate)';

        print_r($sql);
```

the array `$currency` is:

```
Array ( 
   [0] => Array ( [USD] => 73.63 [EUR] => 79.97 ) 
   [1] => Array ( [USD] => 74.05 [EUR] => 80.53 ) 
)
```

Comment: (1) you are missing the parenthesis around your values, i.e. `VALUES (val1,val2)` -> `... VALUES (".implode(', ', $currency[0]).') ON ...`. (2) Your `implode(', ', $currency[0]).'` is resulting in `73.63, 79.9`, not `'USD', 73.63`, which provides invalid value for `code`. (3) you show `$sql` but never show that it is executed, i.e. `dbDelta($sql);`

Comment: I converted the array and print_r the sql but is not inserting the values in the db, what is wrong with it? :  INSERT INTO pr_cbrrate (code, rate) VALUES ('USD', 73.82) , ('EUR', 80.21) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE rate = VALUES(rate)

Comment: after adding this it works: //update the database
    if($wpdb->query($sql) === false){
     return new WP_Error( 'updateRates', __('Failed updating the database table', 'xoogu-currency-conversion'), $wpdb->last_error );
    }